# Compile C to MIPS Assembly in 7 instructions?

Tags: c, mips, compiler-optimization

I just took a final exam and there was a question that seemed impossible given the restrictions. I'd be happy to be proven wrong but as far as I checked around, at least all my classmates agreed with my conclusion. Here's the question and the answer(s) I provided:

A C program snippet is provided as follows:

```
c = a + b + 6;
while (c > 5) {
  c = c - a;
  b = b + 1;
}
```

Write the equivalent in MIPS assembly using at most 7 instructions, using only the following instruction set:

```
add, addi, sub, subi, slt, slti, bne
```

a, b and c are accessible through the registers $t0, $t1 and $s0 respectively. You may use other registers as necessary but you may not assume any initial value.

Here's the answer I gave in as few lines as I could:

```
      add $s0, $t0, $t1
      addi $s0, $s0, 6
loop: slti $t2, $s0, 6
      bne $t2, $0, skip
      sub $s0, $s0, $t0
      addi $t1, $t1, 1
skip: subi $t2, $t2, 1
      bne $t2, $0, loop
```

I thought about it for a good 30 minutes during the 3 hour exam and I came up with two possibilities that the professor could have mistaken on the question. The more likely to me is that he was expecting us to program a `do-while` loop. The other less likely is that we were allowed to use `beq` in addition to the other instructions. Here are my answers for those:

do-while:

```
      add $s0, $t0, $t1
      addi $s0, $s0, 6
loop: sub $s0, $s0, $t0
      addi $t1, $t1, 1
      slti $t2, $s0, 6
      subi $t2, $t2, 1
      bne $t2, $0, loop
```

`beq` allowed:

```
      add $s0, $t0, $t1
      addi $s0, $s0, 6
loop: slti $t2, $s0, 6
      bne $t2, $0, skip
      sub $s0, $s0, $t0
      addi $t1, $t1, 1
skip: beq $t2, $0, loop
```

I challenge anyone to find a shorter answer or to conclusively demonstrate that a shorter answer isn't possible, this has been bugging me a lot.

## Update

I reviewed my final grade with my professor, and while he refused to provide an answer, he claimed that half the class got it correct. I found it unfair that my professor failed to provide proof of an existing answer while using that as the basis to deduct points from my exam, but there's not much I can do to argue my point, and would be unwise to pursue considering that with the curve for the low average on the final, I earned a 4.0 for the class.

I was still skeptical though, because I had found that he misgraded one of my Verilog code snippets that I had gotten full credit for after reviewing my final with him, so I found someone who got full credit for the MIPS assembly problem. He told me his strategy but couldn't remember his exact answer so I helped him recreate it, basing off of @Smac89's answer:

```
      addi $t2, $t0, 6   # d = a + 6
      add $s0, $t2, $t1  # c = d + b
      bne $t2, $t0, comp # (d != a) ? comp
loop: sub $s0, $s0, $t0  # c = c - a;
      addi $t1, $t1, 1   # b = b + 1;
comp: slti $t2, $s0, 6   # d = (c < 6)
      subi $t2, $t2, 1   # invert the flag
      bne $t2, $0, loop  # !(c < 6) ? loop
```

So, this doesn't work either. The specific strategy he employed was that he had a guaranteed branch at the top of the loop and that he checked the condition at the bottom in two lines. However I can't think of a way to use `slt` or `slti` to create a valid flag to check with `bne`. It's possible that the professor may have misgraded whatever he attempted in 7 lines.

In conclusion, I still don't have an answer.

Comment: Depends, are a, b and c signed or unsigned? If a and b are unsigned, it can be simplified to  `do ... while();` because c would always start off greater than 5.  Also, (I think) with some math you can pull the +6 down into the conditional.

Comment: Based on the fact that the allowed instructions were for signed integers, I'd make an educated guess that a, b, and c are signed. And you can't assume c is greater than 5 in either case anyway because of the possibility of integer overflow. Keep in mind though that everything I've said is the only information that was given to me on the exam.

Comment: The reason you couldn't do it is because you're using a loop.  Pretty sure you can solve this in constant time.

Comment: @xaxxon please elaborate, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: b + 6 - (X\*a) > 5 -- solve for X so  b = b + X  and  C = C - X\*a  --- there may be some off by one errors in there.   and I don't actually know if you can do that in less than 7 MIPS instructions

Comment: X * a < b + 1 -- what's your point?

Comment: once you solve for X, you can simply assign values for `b` and `c` directly without a loop.

Comment: @xaxxon not when you're not allowed to use multiplication or division instructions, so that's rather moot.

Comment: oh, oops.  I missed that part.

Comment: If it's any consolation I suspect my professor never actually attempted the problem himself and just assumed it was possible in 7 instructions or less.

Comment: FWIW, it's a silly question for an exam IMHO. I don't know what the class was exactly but it reads more of a "brain teaser" than exam-worthy material.

Comment: @JeffMercado I agree with your assessment of the question, which is part of my frustration in the first place. To protect the privacy of my professor, I'm not going to disclose the class this was for.

Comment: go ask another professsor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
      addi $s1, $t0, 6     # d = a + 6
      add $s0, $s1, $t1    # c = d + b
loop: slti $t2, $s0, 6     # while (is c less than 6? i.e. c is not greater than 5) 
      bne $t2, $zero, exit # (c <= 5)? exit
      sub $s0, $s0, $t0    # c = c - a;
      addi $t1, $t1, 1     # b = b + 1;
      bne $s1, $t0, loop   # (True condition to loop: d != a)
exit:
```

Comment: ok, but what does b > 0 have to do with looping again?  Shouldn't that just be a "while true" type statement?

Comment: Can't use `b` instruction or `j`, so kinda clutching at feathers for that one. Not even sure it is the best condition to use

Comment: you know the value of t2, right?  why not use that in the last line?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. I like the idea but since I'm including the possibility of integer overflow and/or of b being signed, I can't assume that its post increment value is greater than 0. That's a very good attempt though.

Comment: @xaxxon, yea the value of t2 is 0 at that point, but I have to use `bne`. Does bne allow the use of immediate values? Can I do `bne $t2, 1, loop`?

Comment: `bne` only works with registers, it doesn't take immediate values unfortunately.

Comment: remove line 2.  old line 3 now gets compared against 0 instead of 6.  old line 7 now BNE's on t2 and s0 (if s0 is 0 we're done anyhow).new last line adds 6 to c.

Comment: I just found it can be used with immediate values as well. It is apparently an I-type instruction

Comment: Huh.  That's not what I'm seeing here, but I have no assumptions this is authoritative.. http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html  I think my answer works regardless, though.

Comment: @Smac89 [MIPS green sheet](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) does confirm it is immediate type but notice it ignores the immediate value specified. Its inputs are restricted to `rt` and `rd` registers.

Comment: Just being a stickler here but can you provide documentation that supports $ra not being equal to 0 in all cases? I'm not entirely certain we were allowed to assume that on our exam

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, you are right. That register is only updated by the `jal` instruction which basically copies the pc value to $ra. I have used something else as the loop

Comment: Now that is pretty solid. Even though the exit label is on the 8th line I might make this the accepted answer; you've put in a lot of effort.

Comment: Never again dude. This was like optimisation level 7. I wonder what a compiler would have come up with if we use the highest optimisation level on it. I think GCC can produce MIPS. Will try this tomorrow

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out it is possible. I'll post my answer in a few hours as part of the question.

Comment: Well I thought I had it but when thinking it out in my head I forgot I would need to invert the flag...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts still cracking away at this I see. I admire your tenacity :)

Answer (score 4):

Building off Smac89's answer, this guarantees that C isn't 0 unless the loop is done, so the value of C can be used to branch on.

```
      add  $s0, $t0, $t1    # c = a + b
loop: slti $t2, $s0, 0      # while (is c less than 0? 
      bne  $t2, $zero, exit # (c > 5)
      sub  $s0, $s0, $t0    # c = c - a;
      addi $t1, $t1, 1      # b = b + 1;
      bne  $t2, $s0, loop   # Loop again unless s0 is 0 -- then we're done
exit: addi $s0, $s0, 6      # add the missing 6
```

Comment: I'm trying to think of edge cases that might invalidate this, but it seems to work as far as I can tell..

Comment: I guess you don't even need the t2 in line 6.. just use $0

Comment: Just two minor corrections, you need to change the `add` in line 7 to `addi` since it takes an immediate value. You can also change `slti` to `slt` and use $0 instead if you want, but that's just personal taste. I'll think about this tomorrow morning when I'm more awake and if I still like it I'll accept. Here's an upvote.

Comment: Thanks.   Yeah as you pointed out, I don't know mips asm -- I was just trying to understand the concepts not the syntax :)   reading the docs again, now I see.  fixed the add/addi.

Comment: Ooh.. I just realized, the `bne` on line 6 is incorrect. Common edge case: when c is exactly 0, you'll increment it back to 6 which is greater than 5, in which case it should have looped again. Nice try though.

Comment: It's funny.. if greater than were allowed I'd have some interesting solutions.  These numbers feel very carefully selected.   When you get your results back, PLEASE post the answer.